Commit a Crime and spell copies
I wonder if copies of spells (like the ones created by Storm) trigger the "Commit a Crime" ability. The rule on the MTG wiki is as follows:


Rules


From the glossary of the Comprehensive Rules (July 30, 2024—Bloomburrow)
Crime
Targeting an opponent, anything that opponent controls, and/or any cards in an opponent’s graveyard is a crime. See rule 700.13.


From the Comprehensive Rules (July 30, 2024—Bloomburrow)
700.13. Some cards refer to committing a crime. A player commits a crime as that player casts a spell, activates an ability, or puts a triggered ability on the stack and that spell or ability targets at least one opponent; at least one permanent, spell, or ability an opponent controls; and/or at least one card in an opponent’s graveyard.


From the first paragraph I understand that the spell copies would be crimes. But from the second paragraph I understand that they shouldn't be because the copies are not cast.

No, creating a copy of a spell does not commit a crime, no matter what the copy targets.
In that quotation from the wiki, the first paragraph is the glossary definition, while the second is the actual rule that defines committing a crime. The rule is what has actual weight in determining how the game works, and the rule does not include copying a spell in the list of things that count as committing a crime.

Your bolded answer is a little ambiguous. The act of copying a spell can be a crime, since some spell-copying abilities do target the spell. It might be better to say something like "You cannot commit a crime with a copied spell".

Still a little ambiguous, perhaps something explicit that the act of copying an opponents spell itself will be a crime, but the copied spell itself won't be. Narset's Reversal for example is one crime, not two or zero.

The act of copying an opponent's spell is not itself a crime. Casting a spell that targets a spell an opponent controls is a crime, but that's a separate issue.

@murgatroid99 This brings us to the same place we were with your vexing bauble answer, you addressing the letter of the question but not the issues around it which are likely to be the source of confusion among less expert players, the kind who misunderstand what they saw happen and then come to ask questions about it, saying that's a different thing or a separate issue when it's possible that it's the entire underlying issue they didn't understand causing them to ask a tangential question.

I actually don't know what would be a better way to express this. I have tried to address the confusion expressed in the question directly and concisely. I think that saying that copying a spell can sometimes commit a crime will increase ambiguity if anything because the most literal reading of that statement is factually untrue. If you need the precise details of the rule, the text of it is in the question.

For what it's worth, I think this is a fine answer. MtG is such a broad game that trying to guess what underlying issue the poster has is as likely to add more confusion than reduce it; the poster has the ability to refine their question and/or comment on this answer if they want to.

@PhilipKendall and stack exchange is meant to be a knowledge base where people can look up their questions that someone else already asked to find an answer, thus being more comprehensive about the possible misunderstandings is a good thing, rather than just addressing the letter of the question.

I think this answer is correct because I made a specific question about spell copies no spell copying.

Copying a spell and choosing new targets for the copy isn't a crime, so that in and of itself won't cause any crime triggers, however there are two areas around copying spells that might:

You may cast the copy - While this doesn't really happen for spells on the stack, there still are many cards that deal with imprinting spells, exiling them from graveyard or selecting them from the hand and copying them, these copies then get cast, often without paying their mana cost and since they are cast, if they target an opponent or anything belonging to them, then that is a crime.
Copying opponent spells - More likely is there is a crime cast when you go to copy your opponent's spell. Cards like Narsets' Reversal, Twincast or Fork all let you copy a spell, but you aren't casting that copy. However because you are targeting an opponent's spell on the stack, that part of the process is a crime, just as it would be if you were targeting it with a spell like Counterspell.

